# Permissions of /Users keep changing back to drwxrwxrwx

Tags: itunes, macos, icloud, permission, find-my-mac

I use the Disk Utility to repair it. But the permissions change back after reboot.

> Permissions differ on “private/etc/aliases”; should be lrwxr-xr-x ;
>   they are -rwxr-xr-x . 
>   Permissions differ on “Users”; should be drwxr-xr-x ; they are drwxrwxrwx . 
>   Permissions differ on “Users/Shared”; should be drwxrwxrwt ; they are drwxrwxrwx .

System: Mac OS X 10.9.3

Comment: FYI, this appeared on my system, but when I grabbed a virgin 10.9.2 virtual machine and applied the 10.9.3 update from the Apple update .dmg, it did not appear.  Not sure why.

Comment: More details about this bug: http://derflounder.wordpress.com/2014/05/16/users-folder-being-hidden-with-itunes-11-2-installed-and-find-my-mac-enabled/ "It is important that Find My Mac be disabled before the permissions fix is run and also that Find My Mac remain disabled."

Comment: Thanks! You should write that up as an answer, since it's pretty definitive.

Comment: I didn't see the comments here when I answered, so feel free to self answer or edit mine :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This problem was caused by a bug introduced by an Apple software update. [iTunes 11.2.1 has been released](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT6251) to fix the issue.

> iTunes 11.2.1
>
> Impact: A local user can compromise other local user accounts
>
> Description: Upon each reboot, the permissions for the /Users and /Users/Shared directories would be set to world-writable, allowing modification of these directories. This issue was addressed with improved permission handling.

This vulnerability was assigned the security identifier CVE-2014-1347.

Comment: This is now the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem where iCloud's Find My Mac interacts poorly with an iTunes update. (Specifically iTunes 11.2)

The fix and cause are documented expertly on Rich Trouton's blog:

- http://derflounder.wordpress.com/2014/05/16/users-folder-being-hidden-with-itunes-11-2-installed-and-find-my-mac-enabled/

The fix is to disable find my Mac and then [run a script](https://github.com/rtrouton/rtrouton_scripts/tree/master/rtrouton_scripts/unhide_users_and_fix_permissions) to repair the permissions and visibility of the potentially affected folders. This will likely be fixed rapidly by Apple since it can cause some serious issues and confusion when the /Users folders are incorrectly secured.

Answer (score 1):

I've exactly the same problem after updating to 10.9.3 yesterday but with slightly different folders...

Users folder same problem as with yours

Users/Shared same problem as with yours

and

Applications/Safari.app/Contents/Resources/Safari.help/Contents/Resources/index.html

should be: Irwxr-xr-x

is: -rwxr-xr-x

Doesn't matter what I'll try, after the next reboot the problem say's hello again.

Well I've not the chance to test it yet but you might wanna give the following a try:

Start your computer with Alt + CMD + P + R in order to a PRAM reset. 
Start your computer with CMD + R for recovery partition boot Launch Disc Utility and repair the permissions. Quit Disk Utility and open the Terminal (Utilities -->> Terminal) and type:

```
cd /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD (or the name of your partition) 
chmod 755 Users 
chmod 755 Users/Shared 
chflags nohidden Users 
chflags nohidden Users/Shared
```

Restart, normally everything should be back to normal

Comment: Actually, the restart triggers the bug again, so you'll need to disable Find My Mac to prevent a reversion of the permissions each reboot. The commands here look excellent for fixing the issue until the next reboot, though.