# Changed /Users folder permission at boot time

Tags: macos, terminal, permission

Some application (or script) changes the permission of my `/Users` folder from 755 to 777 at every boot. So, when I change it back to 755 (or repair perm with DiskUtility) it is good until the next reboot.

Is any way run `strace` or something like at boot time to trace down who changes the permission?

Comment: Which version of iTunes are you running? See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130917/permissions-of-users-keep-changing-back-to-drwxrwxrwx for why this might be important

Comment: @patrix - GREAT link! Thank you. Going to check and report back.. ;)

Comment: @patrix was iTunes 11.2 (installed on may.17). Todday installed 11.2.1 (and os x update 10.9.3) and the problem is gone! So, probably the iTunes was guilty. :) Please, write your comment as answer - will accept it, it pointed me to the right direction. Thank you.